# Rails before_save not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a before-save action that is supposed to assign a user to a default role, but on creation a user is not assigned a role.

My code:

```
 before_save :assign_default_role, if: Proc.new { |user| user.role == nil }

  def assign_default_role
    self.role = Role.where(code: 'user').first
  end
```

Comment: use `before_create` here

Comment: Are you sure you have 'user' role in the database?

Comment: Try adding some debug statements in the assign_default_role method and creating a user in rails console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `before_create` here.

Comment: `before_save` is before a model update. I think the behavior changed in rails 3

Comment: [The documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) indicates that `before_save` is called prior to `before_create` on new records. If `before_create` works, `before_save` should too.

Comment: Correct in theory. In practice, I know that with Rails 3.2, my `before_save` weren't called on create

Comment: I just created a sample Rails 3.2.13 project to test with - it definitely fires when a new record is saved. https://gist.github.com/cheald/5745739 -- maybe something else is going on here?

Comment: hey, you're the guy from shadowcraft-ui ? fun stuff